# Use of base64 encoding when piping

Tags: pipe, equals

I am trying to do the following:

```
echo "Hallo Welt" | signal-cli -u +49xxxxx send -g 5JY0o+sDPsmbcpx44iIQ==
```

(the value after "-g" is a base64 encoded value)

However, this fails, as the two equal signs at the end of the base64 encoded value are stripped from the line and the program signal-cli complains of not knowing "5JY0o+sDPsmbcpx44iIQ". How can I make sure that the two equal signs are not lost in this piping sequence?